# How can I get the desired data in the list in flutter?

Tags: excel, list, flutter, dart, iterable

I have a list that I read from excel. Here I want to get data with index number 1 and 3 of the lists. For example, I just want to get "ad" and "name" values.

example: [tr, ad, en, name]= [ad, name]

debug=I/flutter (25765): ([Dil1, Kelime1, Dil2, Kelme2], [tr, ad, en, name], [tr, öğrenci, en, student], [en, teach, tr, öğren])

row type is Iterable<List>

```
Future readExcel() async {
        var excelfileDetails = new Word();
    
        var file = excelPath;
        var bytes = File(file).readAsBytesSync();
        var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
        print('${excel}');
    
        print(excel.tables.keys); //sheet Name
        print(excel.tables[excel.tables.keys.first]!.maxCols);
        print(excel.tables[excel.tables.keys.first]!.maxRows);
        final row = excel.tables[excel.tables.keys.first]!.rows
            .map((e) => e.map((e) => e!.value).toList());
        print(row);
```

Comment: You want this output: `[Kelime1, Kelme2], [ad, name], [öğrenci, student], [teach, öğren]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse to List before:

```
final row = excel.tables[excel.tables.keys.first]!.rows
        .map((e) => e.map((e) => e!.value).toList()).toList();
```

And then:

```
row.forEach((e){
          int index = row.indexOf(e);
          row[index].removeAt(0);
          row[index].removeAt(1);
        });
```

Output:

```
[Kelime1, Kelme2], [ad, name], [öğrenci, student], [teach, öğren]
```

Comment: thank you for reply. I get error  "The method 'indexOf' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'indexOf'.

Comment: Ok, i have updated the code!

Comment: Thank you very much . It is working. I need learn this topics. Can you should source me for topics list and map etc in flutter....